# How do I dump the buffer when encoding H264 with FFMPEG?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, buffer, h.264

I'm using a c++ library to write images captured from a webcam to an libx264 encoded mp4 file.
The encoding is working properly but when it starts it writes 40 frames to the buffer. When I close the file these frames aren't flushed so about 6 seconds of video are left unwritten (cam is about 6fps).

So i'm calling:

```
out_size = libffmpeg::avcodec_encode_video( codecContext, data->VideoOutputBuffer,data->VideoOutputBufferSize, data->VideoFrame );

// if zero size, it means the image was buffered
if ( out_size > 0 )
{
//... write to file
}
```

I can't see a way of accessing the images that are left in the buffer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got this working using the following code to flush the buffer. Seems that I was searching for the wrong term - should have been "delayed frames"...

```
void VideoFileWriter::Flush(void)
{
if ( data != nullptr )
{
    int out_size = 0;
    int ret = 0;

    libffmpeg::AVCodecContext* c = data->VideoStream->codec;
    /* get the delayed frames */
    while (1) {
        libffmpeg::AVPacket packet;
        libffmpeg::av_init_packet(&packet);

        out_size = libffmpeg::avcodec_encode_video(c, data->VideoOutputBuffer, data->VideoOutputBufferSize, NULL);
        if (out_size < 0) {
            //fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding delayed frame %d\n", out_size);
            break;
        }
        if (out_size == 0) {
            break;
        }
        if (c->coded_frame->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
            packet.pts = av_rescale_q(c->coded_frame->pts,
                          c->time_base,
                          data->VideoStream->time_base);
            //fprintf(stderr, "Video Frame PTS: %d\n", (int)packet.pts);
        } else {
            //fprintf(stderr, "Video Frame PTS: not set\n");
        }
        if (c->coded_frame->key_frame) {
            packet.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
        }
        packet.stream_index = data->VideoStream->index;
        packet.data = data->VideoOutputBuffer;
        packet.size = out_size;

        ret = libffmpeg::av_interleaved_write_frame( data->FormatContext, &packet );
        if (ret != 0) {
            //fprintf(stderr, "Error writing delayed frame %d\n", ret);
            break;
        }
    }
    libffmpeg::avcodec_flush_buffers(data->VideoStream->codec);
}
}
```

Comment: I move # libffmpeg::avcodec_flush_buffers(data->VideoStream->codec);# into the while(1) loop, it doesn't work for me, the symptom is doesn't flush data into disk.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial07.html) is a tutorial regarding ffmpeg with avcodec, stating that avcodec uses some internal buffers which need to be flushed. There is also some code showing how flushing of these buffers is done ("Flushing our buffers").